# How to change defaults within the WPF application template permanently?

Tags: c#, wpf

I don't want to change every XAML file in a new WPF solution (MS VS 2013 Express).
For example, if I make a new project from Templates, Visual C#, WPF Application, the XAML file should show WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" in the Window tag.
Is it possible? How?

Comment: Take a look through this article: [Creating Visual Studio Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247121.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This is possible. If you go to your Visual Studio templates folder for WPF mine is here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\WPF\1033\WPFWindow` and open "Window1.xaml" you can edit the tag to whatever you want. After that go here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache\CSharp\WPF\1033\WPFWindow` and make sure it's the same. It will take effect after closing and reopening Visual Studio.

Comment: Could not find WPF after ...\CSharp\. I have there Data, Reporting, SQL Server and Web.

Comment: Hm...that could be because you're using Visual Studio Express. Not sure if it stores templates the same way.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a bare solution with everything you want and need in a new project
2) <strike>Install this extension https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/57320b20-34a2-42e4-b97e-e615c71aca24 (it's from MS)</strike> (that's only for 2010, you can do #3 from the File menu 2012 and on)
3) Export your project as a template using the above, or via the File menu if the above extension is not needed

Comment: Export Template Wizard is for Visual Studio 2010 and I got an installation failed message. But I have made 1) and 3) as I found in VS 2013 Express, File (after save all) Export Template...